# Getting value of NumericUpDown moves caret position, can I stop this?

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I've noticed that when I request the `Value` of a `NumericUpDown` control in a C# app, the caret is reset to position 0. This is annoying because my app is periodically grabbing the value of the control, so if this happens while a user is typing into it the caret unexpectedly moves, messing with their input.

Is there a way to prevent this, or a workaround? It doesn't seem to have a `SelectionStart` property, otherwise I could have the polling process save the caret position, get the value, then set it back as a decent workaround.

Comment: I can't repro this. I have a timer that gets the value every 3 seconds and sets a label control text to the value. If I'm typing when the value is pulled, the label changes, but nothing happens to the caret. The only time the caret is reset to the beginning is when the numeric value is greater than the maximum set (at which point the value is also set to the maximum).

Comment: hmm...seems to only happen if a formatting event occurs. for example, if I set DecimalPlaces to 2, the caret resets if the string in the field is "36.1", but doesn't if the string is "36.10" and I'm typing in the integer part of the value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the error with the decimal point. In your timer tick event (or wherever you're pulling in the value), try adding this code:

```
numericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 2;

numericUpDown1.Select(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString().Length, 0);
```

You can't get the SelectionStart, but if you select from the end of the current string and set the `selection length` to 0, it should keep the caret in the correct place.

Answer (score 2):

Intervening key up messes up the typing and the cursor in the text, as getting the value messes up the caret position. Hence the iffy solution of getting the `textboxbase` and setting the value of the caret ourselves.

```
    private void numericUpDown_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            NumericUpDown numericUpDownsender = (sender as NumericUpDown);

            TextBoxBase txtBase = numericUpDownsender.Controls[1] as TextBoxBase;
            int currentCaretPosition = txtBase.SelectionStart;
            numericUpDownsender.DataBindings[0].WriteValue();
            txtBase.SelectionStart = currentCaretPosition;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Afternote: So, the solution is to get the private TextBoxBase from the Numericupdown. Besides, I had the NumericUpdown bounded by a databinding. The WriteValue messes up the caret position, as it gets the value and puts it in the datasource. So, i fixed that by getting the caret position before getting the value, and fix it afterwards.